# How to use Material UI theme to make all button text bold

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I'm trying to set `fontWeight: 'bold'` for all of my button elements. I've made various attempts in my `createTheme` function:

```js
export const muiTheme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "poppins",
    button: {
      fontWeight: "bold",
      color: "blue",
    },
  },
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        text: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
          color: "black",
        },
        textPrimary: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
          color: "black",
        },
      },
    },
    MuiButtonBase: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
          color: "black",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

None of the above is having any effect on my code with the exception of the `fontFamily`

Comment: *with the exception of the fontFamily* ... which one? it is working... ?

Comment: There is one fontFamily in the above, under `Typography`. That is working and I can see it applied to my UI. I've tried several `fontWeights` and none of them have any effect. It seems that MUI apply `font: 'inherit'` somewhere in the CSS, and this is overriding any CSS I try to apply.

Comment: There is one fontFamily in the above, under `Typography`. That is working and I can see it applied to my UI. I've tried several `fontWeights` and none of them have any effect. It seems that MUI apply `font: 'inherit'` somewhere in the CSS, and this is overriding any CSS I try to apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the font weight for your `button` in your theme in the `typography` object similar with the below.

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const theme = createTheme({

  typography: {

    button: { // Here is where you can customise the button
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: 700,
    },    
  },  
});
```

Then when using the `Button` MUI component should have the bold text

```
<Button variant="contained">Submit</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the problem was that the font that I'm using (poppins) just doesn't show up bold/regular fontWeight very well.